# Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and $T \in B (H, K)$. Show that $T$ is compact if and only if $T^*T$ is compact.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and $T \in B (H, K)$. Show that $T$ is compact if and only if $T^*T$ is compact.

Comment: What is your definition of a compact operator?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $T$ is compact, then $T^*T$ is compact since $T^*$ is bounded.

Suppose that $T^*T$ compact, let $x_n$ be a bounded sequence, there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $T^*T(x_{n_k})$ is Cauchy. For every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n_k,n_l>N$ implies that 
$\|T^*T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l})\|<c$. There exists $M$ such that $\|x_n\|<M$, we deduce that:

$\langle T^*T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l}),x_{n_k}-x_{n_l}\rangle=\langle T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l}),T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l})\rangle$

$=\|T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l})\|^2\leq \|T^*T(x_{n_k}-x_{n_l})\|\|x_{n_k}-x_{n_l}\|\leq 2cM$. This implies that $T(x_{n_k})$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: in the first part how to conclude that $T^*T$ is compact if T is bounded? And in the end since the series is cauchy and K banach then it converges and this is what we nned, right?